# WPF Datagrid ComboBox options different based on another row value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid where the ItemsSource is set in code-behind for example:

```
var grid = grdEmploy as DataGrid;
grid.ItemsSource = employments; // list of objects
```

In this grid, I have several drop downs being used when editing the row. The options are currently held in a local CollectionViewSource, for example:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatusList"  CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>
```

And set when the window is loaded like so:

```
var statusList= Functions.GetStatuses(); // returns a List<> 
CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("StatusList"));
itemCollectionViewSource.Source = statusList;
```

Then the binding of the column for the grid would look like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employment Status" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding>
                                                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                        <local:AimTypeConverter />
                                                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                                    <Binding Path="EmpStat" />
                                                    <Binding Path="SourceCollection" Source="{StaticResource StatusList}" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding EmpStat}" SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatusList}}"></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This all works great however I have hit a snag whereby one of the columns needs to show different options based on another column. For example if Column A is "1" show Options 2,3, if "2", show Options 3,4 etc.

My thoughts were to load all options into the local list and somehow filter them but I'm not sure how best to do this, any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this using the MVVM pattern would be to define a collection property in the `Employee` class, or whatever you call it, and then return an already filtered collection from this property based on the value of the property bound to "Column A".

I am afraid it doesn't make much sense to define a single source collection in the code-behind if you want to bind to several source collections, filtered or not, in the `DataGrid`. I would recommend you to put your filtering logic in the view model.

Comment: Could you elaborate further please? Are you suggesting if I had this 'Employee' class I could have a property within it for example List<DropdownItem> StatusList {get;set;}, put the dropdown values in there instead of the source collection and change the Binding Path to this? And then another property where the get is filtered?
Sounds good, only issue I may have is I've found properties like this don't update after edit i.e. it would filter the first time but not after edits. 
What would be the benefit of this instead of source collection out of interest?

Comment: To clarify I mean datagrid edits, may be my own lack of knowledge of WPF of course

Comment: Yes, that's what I am suggesting. You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `StatusList` property. Then any UI element bound to it will get updated whenever you set the property to a new value. The benefit over using a single source collection in the view is that you can easily filter the list for each `Employee` using this approach.

Comment: thanks I've done all this and working, however, the update part is still an issue. If I change the first dropdown, the second column does not update until I come off the row entirely and back again. I've added INotify etc. any clues or should this be a new question?